# CSS should work depends html class name structure

Tags: jquery, html, css

If class name structure     `<td class="green red">Red bg</td>`  need Red color bg here

If  class name structure `<td class="red green">Green Bg</td>` need Green color bg here

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99hRX/3/)

I prefer CSS way

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an "ends-with" attribute selector like:

```
tr td[class$='green'] {
    background: green;
}
tr td[class$='red'] {
    background: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AAXv6/

Comment: Perfect Bro , what about  browser support?

Comment: Attribute selectors are supported very well: http://caniuse.com/css-sel2 :)

Comment: its support all browser but this selector match only last word string. be clear before use.

Comment: support Ie 9 , I dont know about ie 8 and older

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following code

```
[class="green red"] {
    background-color: red;
}

[class="red green"] {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tr td[class="red green"]
{
    background:  red;  
}
tr td[class="green red"] 
{
    background: green ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

css first render according to 1st rule and then according to 2nd rule as red & green are two different classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
tr td[class="red green"]
{
    background-color:  red;  
}
tr td[class="green red"] 
{
    background-color: green ;
}
```